# Validate forms on multiple routes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Disclaimer: I'm an Angular noob, this is my first project using it.

I'm currently building an app where the user is to provide lots of data in forms on multiple pages / routes. All data in all forms have to be validated before submitting.

I'm using the provided directives to set validation rules (ngPattern, ngRequired), and it's working well on each of the forms. When all fields in a single are valid, the state of the form on the current page is valid.

My problem is when trying to get the valid state for the forms on the rest of the routes. I've tried declaring the form outside ng-view,

```
<form name="main"><div ng-view></div></form>
```

and having a main form ouside outside ng-view with nested form in each routes partial. Angular is still just validating the currently displayed form. Is this possible to fix, at all? I can smell some hacky workaround here..

Comment: You mean one require  validation for all input fields at all screen?

Comment: Yes. All fields, even the fields in forms on different routes.

Comment: I think that's not possible, because the validation message should be different.

Comment: I'm just talking about getting the state, to prevent the user from submitting the form if there's any invalid fields on any of the pages. Or maybe I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a image for access a form validation states

[image]

[More details see this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation)

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but the valid state is only considering the fields currently displayed.

Comment: hi  rallrall .I am facing the same issue . have u got any workaround. Please let me know...